# how to use one query output into other query in python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use one query output into other. but not getting the correct result. Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
query1 = "select distinct lower(tablename) as tablename from medaff.imedical_metadata where object_type = 'View'"
```

output of above query is :

```
tablename
vw_mdcl_insght
vw_fbms_interactions
```

I want to use above output in other query. Something like this-

```
query2 = "select * from medaff.imedical_business_metadata where objectname in ('vw_mdcl_insght', 'vw_fbms_interactions')"
```

How to do this part in python?

I am using below code to run the query:

```
conn = redshift_conn()

with conn.cursor() as cur:
      query1 = "select distinct lower(tablename) as tablename from medaff.imedical_metadata where object_type = 'View'"
      cur.execute(sql_query)
      result = cur.fetchall()
      print(result)
      conn.commit()

      query2 = "select * from medaff.imedical_business_metadata where objectname in ('vw_mdcl_insght', 'vw_fbms_interactions')"
      cur.execute(sql_query)
      result = cur.fetchall()
      print(result)
      conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use an `in` query:

```
select ibm.*
from medaff.imedical_business_metadata ibm
where ibm.objectname in (select lower(im.tablename) as tablename
                         from medaff.imedical_metadata im
                         where im.object_type = 'View'
                        );
```

It is better to let the database do the work.

Comment: relation "ibm" does not exist

Comment: @Shivam . . . Huh?  `ibm` is a table alias quite clearly defined in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code:

```
query = "select distinct lower(tablename) from medaff.imedical_metadata where object_type = 'View'"
cur.execute(query)
res = cur.fetchall()
print(res)
res = tuple([item[0] for item in res])
res = str(res)
```